# $ a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}(a_{n-1} + 1)}{a_{n-2}}.$ and $ T = 3.73205080..$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, recurrence-relations, closed-form, rational-functions

Consider the following sequence :
Let $a_1 = a_2 = 1.$
For integer $ n > 2 : $

$$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}(a_{n-1} + 1)}{a_{n-2}}.$$

$$ T = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{ a_{k - 1}}.$$

$$T = ??$$

What is the value of $T$ ?

Is there a closed form or integral for $T$?

I get

$$ T = 3.73205080..$$

The convergeance is fast.

Does anyone recognize this ?

——

Edit

So apparantly $ T = 2 + \sqrt 3 $

Let us generalize.

Take $a_1= 1, a_2 > a_1$

And now the whole sequence depends on $y = a_2$.

We thus define

$$ T(y) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{ a_{k - 1}}.$$

We know $T(1) = T(2) = 2 + \sqrt 3 $.

$$T(3) = 4.4415184401122.. $$

Apparantly $T(3) = \frac{7 + 2 \sqrt 10}{3} $ as found ( no proof ) by lhf.

How about a closed form for $T(y)$ ?

Can all of these rational recursions be transformed into a linear recursion ?

———
Update

See also

[About $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}(a_{n-1} + C)}{a_{n-2}} , t(12,13) = \frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479854/about-a-n-fraca-n-1a-n-1-ca-n-2-t12-13-frac32)

Comment: I recognize it as $2+\sqrt3$

Comment: $a_n$ is https://oeis.org/A101879, a sequence of *integers*!

Comment: See also https://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/reach/Barton/b-interp.html

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: My mentor tommy1729. Mid 90’s but he talked about it and related recursions yesterday.

Comment: One of the reasons was that with a_2 = 1 or 2 the sequence is integer despite the fraction recursion. Somos like but simpler in a sense. He considered The number theoretic things of it. Like divisors and primes. I already posted many recursions and questions originating from him.

Comment: He called them “ artistic sequences “

Comment: You may be able to cheat your way out of the question by assuming $$a_n=C_0r^n+C_1+C_2r^{-n},~r>1$$though I'm not sure if this is a sufficiently general form or not...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477954/tommy-s-amazing-new-lim-for-the-golden-number

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479854/about-a-n-fraca-n-1a-n-1-ca-n-2-t12-13-frac32

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: By already knowing the solution to your recurrence a priori, I am able to solve your problem. However, a more interesting question might be why your recurrence is equivalent to
$$a_n=5a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$
and how to see this a priori.

Your recurrence is solved by the sequence (as can be checked by direct calculations)
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{6+(3-\sqrt 3)\cdot(2+\sqrt 3)^n + (2-\sqrt 3)^n\cdot(3+\sqrt 3)}{12}.$$

So \begin{split}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\frac{6+(3-\sqrt 3)\cdot(2+\sqrt 3)^n + (2-\sqrt 3)^{n}\cdot(3+\sqrt 3)}{6+(3-\sqrt 3)\cdot(2+\sqrt 3)^{n-1} + (2-\sqrt 3)^{n-1}\cdot(3+\sqrt 3)}
\\
&= (2+\sqrt 3)\cdot\frac{\frac{6}{(2+\sqrt3)^{n}}+3-\sqrt 3+3+\sqrt 3}{\frac{6}{(2+\sqrt3)^{n-1}}+3-\sqrt 3+3+\sqrt 3}\\
&=(2+\sqrt 3)\cdot\frac{\frac{6}{(2+\sqrt3)^{n}}+6}{\frac{6}{(2+\sqrt3)^{n-1}}+6}
\\&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}(2+\sqrt 3).
\end{split}

I got the closed form for $a_{n+1}$ from [A101879](http://oeis.org/A101879) of the OEIS.

Comment: Your answer is correct ! “ as can easily be checked “, well easily is subjective i would say , but indeed it is true. But how was it found ? Or how should it be found ? In other words is there a nice method ? I assume you just used the OEIS. But there should be a method to find that formula for a_n or at least ( indirectly ) The simpler linear recursion a_n satisfies. How about that ?

Comment: Hi @mick ; Solving the linear recurrence $a_n=5a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ relation is standard theory (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)). However, I don't know how one would notice a priori that both recurrence relations are equivalent...

Comment: See The edit to The OP. Sorry to make it harder after your answered. But maybe this is a better challenge to you ;)

Comment: @lhf Ok (I'll edit it)

Answer (score 2):

Empirical answer to the last question:

$T(y)$ seems to be $\dfrac{A(y)+\sqrt {B(y+2)}}{y}$, where $A(y)$ is [OEIS/A000124](https://oeis.org/A000124) and $B(y)$ is [OEIS/A327319](https://oeis.org/A327319).

Tested for $y=1,2,\dots,6$.

Comment: The author of the conjectured B(y) wrote about a “ fibonacci-Lucas experiment “ at The 2017 Ohio mma Fall meeting. Related ???